# How can I embed a power app with differently sized screens into a sharepoint site?

Tags: site, powerapp, sharepoint-site

I have a PowerApp that uses multiple screens. Some screens need more space than others and have therefore a greater height property.

If I embed the PowerApp via an iframe I have to set a fixed height and width.
Is it possible to allocate the needed height in the sharepoint site so that my app always is as high as the currently displayed screen?

E.g. one screen has a height of 1000px, then the iframe should be this height. But if the next screen has a height of 2000px, the height of the embedded app should adjust to this height and take this much space of my sharepoint site, moving following content further down

Comment: My answer should work for you, and we did not hear from you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to is to work with [Enhanced Power Apps Webpart](https://youtu.be/EFhP4uu0rlo), April did all the required explanation.

It will definitely answer your business need.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Sadly I won't be able to use this webpart. Took a while to figure that out, sorry for that.